# How to programmatically add "@Cascade" to a POJO field (Spring mvc + Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I was wondering if it is possible, instead of doing this:

```
public class Father implements Serializable{    
    ...
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL) <----------------------------------------
    private List<Progeny> progenyList;
    ...
}
```

add a `Cascade` operation at runtime, since sometimes I may need to save `Father` and its`Progeny` and sometimes I may need to save `Father` BUT NOT its `Progeny`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this functionality only in specific places you should rather just call `em.save(progenyList)` instead of `fancyWayToActivateCascadeTemporarily()` before saving the father :)

---

That said:
I believe you can have two entity classes for the same `@Table` that have different annotations.